# Web server access through RT-N66U Router

Tags: networking, router, apache-http-server, home-networking, webserver

Many thanks in advance for your kind support.

I have an Ubuntu LAMP server in my local home network, and based on my observations and debug so far I believe I have some crippling setting in my ASUS RT-N66U Router that's preventing the web server from working across the router.

After a week of debugging, I decided to try swapping in my very, very old D-Link WBR-1310 Router and the problem magically disappeared, so I have reasonably high (but not full) confidence the problem is some setting in my ASUS router.  Or, I have some improbable setting on my server that's somehow binding it to a characteristic of my old router (MAC?)... which seems very unlikely but maybe possible (I did previously use this router on the same network).

The problem isn't a black & white "access blocked" type of error, but rather a crippling slow access that will usually timeout eventually or sometimes manage to load a page after several minutes.  What takes ~5ms to load a simple page across my D-Link router, takes ~2-5 minutes on the ASUS if I'm lucky, while the majority of the time it times out after several minutes.  It sometimes manages to load half of a menu, half of an image, but more often spins and gets nowhere.

**The setup**

```
- LAMP server on a static IP, 192.168.0.101
- Ubuntu 11 (Natty Narwhal)
- A Win7 PC, dynamic IP 192.168.0.200
- ASUS RT-N66U Router, LAN IP 192.168.0.1
- Router has a good WAN IP, internet working fine.
- Router is setup to grant dynamic IPs for a range of 192.168.0.104+
- When swapping in an old D-Link router (problem disappears), with same LAN IP (192.168.0.1)
- Using the raw IP address (192.168.0.101) to access the server
- server and client both wired connections
- IPv6 is disabled 
- VPN & traffic manager disabled
- no cron jobs running on the server.
- No static routes are setup on the router (not daisy chained to anything)
```

**Observations**

```
- Takes minutes (or times out) for a simple page to load across the ASUS router
- Takes milliseconds to load the same page across the DLink router 
- Pinging works fine across the local network to/from the server
- Pinging works for to both the Router LAN IP and its WAN IP
- SSH also appears to be extremely slow (or times out)
- Evidence of some intermittent condition: 
  The server IP appears and disappears in the routers connected client IP list.  
  However, pinging constantly works and the physical connection is never really dropping.  
- Traceroute confirms its just going 1 quick hop on the LAN to the server.
- [Edit] HTTP Internet access from server to outside through router has the same extremely slow/intermittent issue
```

**Debugging so far**

```
- Disabled port forwarding for access from LAN.
- Enabled port 80 forwarding for access from WAN. 
   This replicates the same extremely slow access situation that the LAN is experiencing.
- Did a factory reset on the ASUS router to start clean.
- Upgraded to latest ASUS router firmware. 
- Disabled DNS (but im using the raw IP anyways) on router
- Disabled reverse DNS lookups on server
- Telnet'ed into router to check iptables settings. No packets hitting any deny rule. 
- Disabled firewall on router
- Disabled mysql, SSH services on server
- Problem isn't a specific webpage on the server, happens with any (such as phpmyadmin).
- Checked router system log, server apache2 error logs (log level=debug) 
- Tried changing the server to use a dynamic IP as an experiment 
- Tried grepping to see if the MAC address of my old router appears on my server
```

Also modulated many settings on the server itself (hosts, httpd.conf, apache2.conf, network interface, nsswitch.conf, turning off & restarting numerous services 1 at a time), until finding that the simple router swap completely resolved the problem (with zero change on the server and the same IP settings in the router), so now I'm trying to narrow in on a router configuration issue at this point.

Any ideas on some next steps?  Thanks for your expertise  :)
Simon

Comment: You didn't specify if your server is connected to you ASUS router via Wifi or an Ethernet cable. If it's connected via Ethernet, did you try using a different port on your ASUS router? It's possible you have a bad/faulty Ethernet port.

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks for your comment and idea.  it's using a wired connection (mentioned in post but i can see it being hard to notice).  I'll try a different port, but since the speed is fine for internet access from the server using the same port i won't hold out much hope.  I'll comment on the result. thanks!

Comment: Tried swapping the cables and using different ports in the router, no change.

Comment: Update/clarification, after debugging more today I find the outbound internet access from the server (ie: to google, gmail, etc) displays the same problem.  Previously hadn't noticed this properly.  So the problem seems common to HTTP access to/from the server.  I've also tried putting the server in a DMZ in the router setup, to no avail.   

I'm thinking about installing DD-WRT firmware on the router as a next step...

Comment: I have had some weird buggy issues with port forwarding inward on the same router, switching to rMerlin firmware cleared up all my issues... It is based on stock with many tweaks and enhancements, even works with all the Asus apps and stuff. I would highly recommend it before jumping to DD-WRT/Tomato. https://asuswrt.lostrealm.ca/

Comment: * Grabbed a 3rd Router (Cisco Linksys) to further debug, and it has the same behavior as the ASUS!  So this points back to a Server side setup issue thats uniquely working for the DLink router rather than the ASUS being the culprit.  So, I upgraded to Ubuntu 16 (from 11), but same issue persists.  

*  I also updated the ASUS FW to Merlin, and tried a couple of settings to no avail, but after finding out the 3rd Router behaved the same way I've switched to focus on Server side settings. 

*  Any suggestions on what to look at on the server?